# how to print matched keywords from two lists

Tags: python, regex, string, list

```
jd = "looking for Hadoop Developer Good knowledge of SAP Workflow and SAP HANA"    
tech=['hadoop developer','sap workflow','sap hana']    
string_split = jd.split()    
matched = set(jd) & set(tech)

output:
matched
Out[9]: set()
```

How to print the matched two words like:

```
hadoop developer,sap hana,sap workflow
```

Comment: Do you understand what the code that you have posted is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension will work. Key to this is forcing `jd` to lower since otherwise it won't match correctly.

```
[i for i in tech if i in jd.lower()]
['hadoop developer', 'sap workflow', 'sap hana']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `re.findall` here:

```
import re
print(re.findall("|".join(tech), jd.lower()))
#['hadoop developer', 'sap workflow', 'sap hana']
```

The `|` character is the OR operator in regular expression syntax. We use it to join the terms in `tech`. Then `findall` will return all matches for the pattern in the string.

This is case-sensitive by default, but you can add the `IGNORECASE` flag if you don't want to make your input string lower case.

```
re.findall("|".join(tech), jd, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
#['Hadoop Developer', 'SAP Workflow', 'SAP HANA']
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that depends of your data. If you have a *tech* list with few items, then @pault solution will fit your needs (however I suggest to add word boundaries to the pattern to avoid false positive), but if you have many items you can play with sets.

You have to build a set of all two words sequences and then to find the intersection between it and the set from the tech list.

To find all sequences of two words in *jd*, I use a capture group inside a lookahead assertion. Since a lookahead doesn't consume characters, the pattern is able to find all overlapping sequences of two words: *looking for*, *for hadoop*, *hadoop developer*, ... The `\b` at the beginning and the greedy quantifier for the second `\w` ensure that the match only contains whole words and not parts of words.

```
import re

jd = "looking for Hadoop Developer Good knowledge of SAP Workflow and SAP HANA"    
tech=['hadoop developer','sap workflow','sap hana']

two_words = re.findall('\b(?=(\w+\W*\w+))', jd.lower())
print(','.join(list(set(two_words) ^ set(tech))))
```

[demo](https://eval.in/1040761)